# In a Right Angled Triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In a triangle ABC, Let $\angle$C=$\frac{\pi}{2}$. If $r$ is the inradius and $R$ is the circumradius, then what is the value of $2r+R$.

Options are

1. a+b
2. b+c
3. c+a
4. a+b+c

**My approach.**

Radius of circumcircle, $R$= $\frac{c}{2}$, if $c$ is the side opposite to $\angle$C

let $\Delta$ be the area of the triangle,

so, radius of incircle, $r$= $\frac{\Delta}{s}$, where, $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$

$\Delta$=$\frac{ab}{2}$,

Comment: $R=AB/2$ by Thales' theorem.

Comment: @Dheeraj Kumar what have you tired so far?

Comment: I will write my work below question

Comment: @happymath any suggestions.

Comment: @DheerajKumar what do want to prove here you already have an expression what do you want to simplify it into?

Comment: @DheerajKumar, I'll be amazed if this produces something extra-ordinary . We can use http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Inradius

Comment: how can we find 2r+R

Comment: @DheerajKumar what are given to you? because this value does not seem to be constant for all right triangles

Comment: sides are given a,b and c. c being the hypotenous

Comment: $r = \frac{a+b-c}{2}$ by considering the tangent points of the inscribed circle.

Comment: @DheerajKumar none of the options are correct since consider $c=5 $ $a=4 $ $b=3$ none of the options match

Comment: how you got c=3

Comment: @DheerajKumar I am just evaluating it in a special case where the triangle is $3-4-5$

Comment: @happymath which simplified form of $2r+R$ are you using

Comment: @DheerajKumar $\frac{2ab}{a+b+c}+\frac{c}{2}$

Comment: @happymath it is a multiple choice question from my class test.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: @abel vote down? i did'nt voted you down

Comment: i did not mean you downvoted my answer; i meant someone downvoted the question and i was wondering why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the the triangle is a right angle triangle helps: $R = c/2$ because the hypotenuse is the diameter of the circumcircle. now if you look at the tangent from $C$ to the incircle you will see that $r = s - c$ where $s = (a + b + c)/2$ is half of the perimeter. putting these together $$ 2r + R = (a + b + c). $$

edit: as pointed out by @peterwhy, i made an arithmetical error $r = s- c, R = c/2$ gives you $$r + 2R = (a+b+c)/2.$$

here is how you can see that $r = s - c.$ if you look at the four points: center $I$ of the incircle, two contact points where the circle touches the arms of the right angle($BC, AC)$, and the corner $C.$ these four points make up a square. rememeber we have already established the points contacts from $C$ are at a distance $s-c$ from the corner which does not depend $C$ being a right angle. that follows by splitting $b$ as the sum of $s-c$ and $s-a$ and symmetrically for $a$ and $b.$

it is always a good idea to draw a figure on a piece of paper first.(sorry i dont know how to put up a figure here but i did this work on a piece of paper first). the text book, goeometry reviisted by coxeter and greitzer is a good one to have if you can get it around where you live. good luck.

Comment: how you got $r=s-c$

Comment: But $2r+R = 2s - 2c + \frac c2 = a + b -c + \frac c2$.

Comment: @peterwhy your answer is not correct see options

Comment: the length of tangents from $A, B,$ and $C$ to the incircle are $s-a, s-b$ and $s - c$ in any triangle. you can get this by using the fact that tangent from a point to a circle are of the same length. start with one length and go around the sides you equating tangent from the vertices and will get the result i claimed.

Comment: @DheerajKumar your answers are not correct see above.

Comment: @DheerajKumar OK, then upvote his answer and succeed in your class test.

Comment: @abel can you explain with calculations how you got $r=s-c$ I still can't figure it out

Comment: i will add an explanation in my answer.

Comment: thanks @abel I never knew that relation. thank you for explaining that to me and i will definitely check the book you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It’s converse also true 
i.e. $r+2R=s \implies$ triangle is right angle triangle.

As given condition equivalent to $\prod \sin\left (\frac{\pi-2A}{4}\right)=0 $