# How do you derive that the inradius in a right triangle is $r=\frac{a+b-c}2$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

If we have a [right triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle) then the [inradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inradius) is equal to $$r=\frac{a+b-c}2,$$
where $c$ is the hypothenuse and $a$ and $b$ are the legs.

This formula is mentioned in various places and it can be useful both in geometric problems and in problems on Pythagorean triples.<sup>1</sup>

**Question:** How can one derive this formula?

---

<sup>1</sup>It is stated [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#Inradius_and_circumradius) (in the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Right_triangle&oldid=1046460385#Inradius_and_circumradius) without a reference). Some posts on this site where this equation (or something closely related) is mentioned:
[If the radius of inscribed circle in a right triangle is $3 cm$ and the non-hypotenuse side is $14cm$, calculate triangle's area.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247239/if-the-radius-of-inscribed-circle-in-a-right-triangle-is-3-cm-and-the-non-hypo),
[Prove the inequality $R+r > \sqrt{2S}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515106/prove-the-inequality-rr-sqrt2s/2515115#2515115),
[In a Right Angled Triangle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063198/in-a-right-angled-triangle/1063225#1063225),
[How do I find the radius of the circle which touches three sides of a right angled triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290251/how-do-i-find-the-radius-of-the-circle-which-touches-three-sides-of-a-right-angl/2290406#2290406), [Is there a way to see this geometrically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297169/is-there-a-way-to-see-this-geometrically/2297290#2297290), [Range of inradius of a right Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69553/range-of-inradius-of-a-right-triangle/69555#69555).

---

<sup>I will mention that I would be able to derive this myself in some way. (And some of the posts linked above in fact include something which basically leads to a proof.)
Still, I think that it is to have somewhere this nice fact as a reference. And I wasn't able to find on this site a question specifically about this problem.
I can post an answer myself - but I wanted to give others an opportunity to make a post first.</sup>

Comment: One possible way: let $I$ be the incenter and suppose that incircle touches legs $AC$ and $BC$ at points $P$ and $Q$, respectively. Then, $PIQC$ is a square, so $r=PI=CP$.

Comment: A sketch is outlined here https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Inradius

Comment: In the last example among your links, it is neatly proved (by Intelligenti pauca) (see the edit). Can you see that he says $c=a+b-2r$?

Comment: @ACB Yes, I have explicitly mentioned in the question that some of the links give a proof.  Still, I considered posting question like this useful. 1. It is about this specific formula. 2. The answers collect various proofs. 3. If somebody is searching for a proof of this formula on MSE, the title "Is there a way to see this geometrically?" won't be the first guess for a post where to find something like that.

Comment: Another way: we know area of right triangle is $ab/2$ and we know $A = r \cdot s$ where is $s$ is sub-perimeter. So $r (a+b+c) = ab$. Multiplying both sides by $(a+b-c)$, we get $r \cdot (2ab) = ab (a+b-c)$

Comment: @MathLover Why not expanding that comment into an answer?

Comment: @MartinSleziak I did not check the links you shared so wasn't sure whether this answer was already given earlier or not, did not want to duplicate

Comment: Another related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2274268/947379

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Let the tangent points be $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ labelled in the usual way.
Then, since tangents from a point to a circle have equal length, $CB'=r=CA'$.

Therefore, for the same reason, $$AB'=AC'=b-r$$ and $$BA'=BC'=a-r$$
And since $AC'+BC'=c$, we get $a-r+b-r=c$ and hence the result.

Comment: +1. One can readily show that, for *any* triangle, the tangent segments from $A$, $B$, $C$ *always* have lengths $a'=(-a+b+c)/2$, $b'=(a-b+c)/2$, $c'=(a+b-c)/2$, respectively. (Just solve the system $a=b'+c'$, $b=c'+a'$, $c=a'+b'$.) When there's a right angle, the inradius is necessarily equal to the corresponding tangent segment.

Comment: After noticing that it is the same picture, I wondered whether the images was taken from Wolfram MathWorld article on [Right Triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RightTriangle.html). (Basically by accident I have noticed the same picture also in [another post on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69553/range-of-inradius-of-a-right-triangle/69555#69555).)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Probably - I just grabbed the first one I could find

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below the *question*, the image in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2297290/947379) is very comprehensive.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

$$\large \Delta=\color{green}\blacktriangle+\color{red}\blacktriangle+\color{blue}\blacktriangle$$
$$\frac{ab}2=\frac{ar}2+\frac{br}2+\frac{cr}2$$
$$ab=(a+b+c)r$$
$$ab(a+b-c)=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)r$$
$$ab(a+b-c)=[(a+b)^2-c^2]r$$
$$ab(a+b-c)=(\underbrace{a^2+b^2-c^2}_{0}+2ab)r$$
$$ab(a+b-c)=2ab\cdot r$$
$$r=\frac{a+b-c}2$$

Answer (score 4):

[image: Triangle square]

By the squares method,
$$r^2+r(a-r)+r(b-r)=r\,\dfrac{a+b+c}2,$$
$$2(a+b-r)=a+b+c,$$
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{r=\dfrac{a+b-c}2.}}$$

Then
$$R+r=\dfrac c2+r=\dfrac{a+b}2\le\sqrt{ab\mathstrut}\,=\sqrt{2S}\,.$$

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that I don't think I've seen before (but don't doubt exists in the literature):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}r&=\frac{\Delta}s\\&=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}
\\&=\sqrt{\frac{({a+b-c})({a-b+c})({-a+b+c})}{8s}}
\\&=\sqrt{\frac{({a+b-c})[c^2-({a-b})^2]}{8s}}
\\&=\sqrt{\frac{({a+b-c})(2ab)}{8s}}
\\&=\sqrt{\frac{({a+b-c})}{2}.\frac{\Delta}{s}}
\\&=\sqrt{\frac{({a+b-c})}{2}.r}\end{align*}$$
$$\implies r=\frac{a+b-c}2,$$

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the right-angled triangle into 3 triangles of bases $a$, $b$ and $c$ and the same height $r$（the in-radius）yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{r a}{2}+\frac{r b}{2}+\frac{r c}{2} &=\frac{a b}{2} \\
r(a+b+c) &=a b \\
r &=\frac{a b}{a+b+c} \cdot \frac{a+b-c}{a+b-c} \\
&=\frac{a b(a+b-c)}{a^{2}+b^{2}+2 a b-c^{2}} \\
&=\frac{a+b-c}{2}\quad \left(\because c^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can consider the triangle formed by $(a, 0), (0, b), (0, 0)$ in the Cartesian Plane and proceed to find the point of intersection of the angular bisectors.

One angular bisector is clearly the line $y = x$.

For the other one, assume that the angle at (a, 0) to be $\theta$. The angular bisector is $y = -\tan \frac{\theta}{2}x+ a\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$.

The point of intersection these lines is
$$
\left(\frac{a\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{1 + \tan\frac{\theta}{2}}, \frac{a\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{1 + \tan\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)
$$
which means that the inradius is just $\frac{a\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{1 + \tan\frac{\theta}{2}}$. Starting from $\tan\theta = \frac{b}{a}$, it is easy to show that $\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{c - a}{b}$.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{1 + \tan\frac{\theta}{2}} &= \frac{a}{2}\tan\theta \left(1 - \tan \frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{b}{2} \left(1 - \frac{c - a}{b}\right) \\
& = \frac{a+b-c}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Labeling in [Linked Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Right_triangle&oldid=1046460385#Inradius_and_circumradius) was incorrect. Vertex $C$ should have been more suitably labeled/placed at the vertex containing the right angle. Vertices  A,B,C ordering should correctly be:

[image]

We have in-radius $r$

$$r=\frac{\Delta}s =\sqrt{\frac{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s^2}}=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$$

on simplification using the cut & pasted image above

[image]

also depicts a correct relation for in-radius $r$ as can be verified *by algebraic cross-multiplication* leading to Pythagoras thm of the right triangle:

$$ (a+b)^2-c^2= 2ab \to c^2= a^2+b^2. $$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
r &=\frac{\Delta}{s} \\
 &=\frac{\frac{ab}2}{\frac{a+b+c}2} \\
 &=\frac{ab}{a+b+c} \\
&=\frac{\frac{(a+b)^2-c^2}{2}}{a+b+c}\\
&=\frac{(a+b-c)(a+b+c)}{2(a+b+c)}\\
\Rightarrow r=\frac{a+b-c}2
\end{align}