# Triangle inequality in an ellipse

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, conic-sections

In the standard ellipse of variable axes dimensions  $( a, b, c= \sqrt{a^2-b^2}), $

[image]

what is the geometrical significance of triangle inequality difference for variable $(2a-2c)$ in the first and third cases?

The second case result is known.. in the ongoing question [in-circle diameter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4280968/how-do-you-derive-that-the-inradius-in-a-right-triangle-is-r-fracab-c2).

It was ensured to be geometrically constructible and  answer interesting... hope forms my part of problem solving attempt.