# Find the measure of the relationship $\frac{1}{r_1} - \frac{1}{r} $in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In In a right triangle $ABC$ ($A=90°$) with inradio $r$, cevian $AD$ is drawn in such a way that the inradium of $ABD$ and $ADC$ are equal to $r1$.If $AD=2$, calculate $\frac{1}{r1}-\frac{1}{r}$ (Answer:0,5).

My progress:

[image]

$\triangle CED \sim \triangle CAB  \\
\frac{CE}{AC}=\frac{DE}{AB}=\frac{CD}{BC}\\
\triangle BDL \sim \triangle BCA\\
\frac{DL}{AC}=\frac{BD}{BC}=\frac{LB}{AB}\\
CE = CI\\
BK = BL$

but I still haven't found the necessary relationship to finalize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what seems to be an unnecessarily-complicated solution.

[image]

Define $b:=|AC|$, $c:=|AB|$, $d:=|AD|$, $p:=|BD|$, $q:=|CD|$. Let $r$ be the inradius of $\triangle ABC$, and let $s$ be the common inradius of $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$.

We know $$\text{inradius}\cdot \text{perimeter} = 2\,\text{area}$$ so we can write
$$\begin{align}
s(c+d+p) &= 2|\triangle ABD|=\frac{p}{p+q}\cdot 2|\triangle ABC| = \frac{p}{p+q}\, r (b+c+p+q) \tag1\\[8pt]
s(b+d+q) &= 2|\triangle ACD|=\frac{q}{p+q}\cdot 2|\triangle ABC| = \frac{q}{p+q}\, r (b+c+p+q) \tag2
\end{align}$$
Solving this linear system for $b$ and $c$ gives
$$
b = -q-d + \frac{2 d q r}{(p + q)(r - s)} \qquad\qquad
c = -p-d + \frac{2 d p r}{(p + q)(r - s)} \tag3
$$

Since $\triangle ABC$ is right, [we also know](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4287653/409)
$$\begin{align}
2r = |AC|+|AB|-|BC| &= b+c-(p+q) \\
&= 2\,\frac{ ds- (p+q)(r-s)}{r - s} \\
\to \qquad (p+q)(r-s) &= ds -r(r-s)\tag4
\end{align}$$
By [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem), we have
$$b^2p+c^2q=(p+q)(d^2+pq) \quad\underset{(3)}{\to}\quad 
 (p + q) s (r - s)= d r (2s-r) \tag5$$

Combining $(4)$ and $(5)$ to eliminate $p+q$ gives

> $$r s (r - s) = d (r - s)^2 \quad\to\quad r s = d (r - s) \quad\to\quad
> \frac1d=\frac1s-\frac1r \tag{$\star$}$$

Substituting $d=2$ gives the specific result for the question as stated. $\square$

---

There's almost-certainly a quicker path to the target relation. Note that
$$s(b+c+2d+p+q)=2|\triangle ABC| = r(b+c+p+q) \qquad\to\qquad \frac1s-\frac1r=\frac{d}{|\triangle ABC|}$$
So, really, "all we have to do" is show $d^2=|\triangle ABC|$. I'm not seeing a particularly *good* way to do that. Even so, looking at this as $2d^2=bc$ gives an easy way to construct an accurate figure in, say, GeoGebra, for further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

In a right triangle, $~b + c = 2r + a$, where $a$ is hypotenuse. If $s$ represents sub-perimeter, then [by law of cotangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cotangents),

$ \displaystyle \frac{s_{\triangle ABC} - b}{r} = \frac{s_{\triangle ABD} - 2}{r_1}$
$ \displaystyle \frac{s_{\triangle ABC} - c}{r} = \frac{s_{\triangle ACD} - 2}{r_1}$

Adding both,
$~\displaystyle \frac{a}{r} = \frac{s_{\triangle ABC} - 2}{r_1} = \frac{r + a - 2}{r_1}$

$ \implies a (r - r_1) = 2r - r^2 \tag1$

By equating area of $\triangle ABC$ to sum of areas of $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$,

$r_1 (a + b + c + 4) = r( a + b + c)$
i.e. $~r_1 (r + a + 2) = r (r + a)$

$\implies a (r - r_1) = r_1 (r + 2) - r^2\tag2$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$ and simplifying we get $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{r_1} - \frac{1}{r} = \frac12$

Comment: you are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Particular case, where triangle is isosceles:

As can be seen in figure a in this case $BC=4$ ; now you can find measures of AB and AC, then use this formula:

$r=\frac Sp$

(where S is area and p is half perimeter) to find $r$ and $r_1$.

$S_{ABC}=\frac{AD\times BC}2=\frac{2\times4}2=4$

$S_{ADB}=\frac 42=2$

$2p_{ABC}=4+4\sqrt 2$

$2p_{ABD}=4+2\sqrt 2$

So we have:

$$x=\frac1{\frac 2{2+\sqrt2}}-\frac 1{\frac 4{2+2\sqrt 2}}=\frac{2+\sqrt2}2-\frac{1+\sqrt 2}2=\frac 12$$
You may also use the fact that the centers or circles $O$ and $O_1$ are collinear and use another method.

[image]

Update: Figure C shows no- isosceles triangle and we have:

$\frac 1{0.569}-\frac 1{0,796}=0.5$

Comment: In my geogebra. my figure gave 0.5

Comment: @petaarantes, I had some error , I corrected them. Also the scale of figure is 10/1.

Comment: I don't understand why the triangle is isosceles..in my figure it is not...
Why area ABC = 4?

Comment: The triangle need not be isosceles. In general, we have 
$$|AB|\cdot |AC|=2|AD|^2$$ (I don't yet have a nice way to show that.)

Comment: @sirous: In your Figure C, do the inradii of the sub-triangles match?

Comment: @sirous: OP says nothing about the sides of $\triangle ABC$, but OP *does* say that "the inradi[i] of $ABD$ and $ADC$ are equal to $r1$", which by transitivity makes them equal to each other. ;) ... I'm afraid I don't understand your comment about my answer. *Of course* the values change as side-lengths change; but they don't change *arbitrarily*. They change subject to the conditions of the exercise (that $\triangle ABC$ has a right angle at $A$, and that $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$ have equal inradii). Those conditions imply the relation I've labeled $(\star)$ ... unless I've erred.

Comment: @Blue, I did not notice that the radii of sub-triangles must be equal. I corrected my answer. It could be considered  as particular case. No need to down vote(I am sure you did not).

Comment: @sirous: I almost-never downvote (and didn't here). I prefer to give constructive criticism. :)

Comment: @Blue, I am sure about it. I also try to do the same.Dow vote discourage but constructive response encourage people.

Comment: @sirous hy..can you see this question.. I can't finish https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503096/regular-heptagon-area-formula?noredirect=1#comment9451992_4503096

Comment: @petaarantes, thanks for informing me. see my hint. plus you did not respond to my answer to this post!