# Regular heptagon area formula

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Be a regular heptagon. Can anyone demonstrate this formula?

[image]
I know:
Let apothem = ap

side = l

$ S=\frac{p.ap}{2}\implies S = \frac{7l.ap}{2}\\
\triangle OBC: OC^2 = a^2+l^2\\
\triangle PAB: b^2+l^2 = PB^2\\
OC^2-a^2=PB^2-b^2$

but i can't go on

Comment: It is easy to see, since the side measures $1$, that $A=\dfrac74\dfrac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{7})}$ and the radius of the corresponding circle $r=\dfrac{1}{2\sin({\pi}{7})}$. From this it follows your answer with a bit of elementary geometry.

Comment: @Piquito Can you finished?

Comment: $b=a+1\cdot\sin(\angle{DCG})$ and $a=1\cdot\sin(\angle{BCG})$. 

What is missing you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @Piquito  still can't understand..you already have the solution in your mind so it becomes easy...You say that $A=\frac{7\frac{cos\pi}{7}}{4 sin\frac{\pi}{7}}$ Where does this relationship come from? Where does the relation of "r" come from? The relations of "a" and "b" are ok. Where will I use them?
If you can clarify better I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You have an isosceles triangle of two sides $r$ and angle $\dfrac{2\pi}{7}$  so the height $h=r\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{7})$.... etc.  This is all I have to say you. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks Thanks for the information

Comment: Could someone finish it still I couldn't find the solution

Comment: A way could be as follow. You have to verify $\dfrac74\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{7})=\sqrt7 ab=\sqrt7(\sin^2(X)+\sin(X)\sin(Y))$ where you know what are $X$ and $Y$. 
On the other hand you can do
$$\sin(7\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{7})=\sin(\pi)=0=\sin\left(4(\dfrac{\pi}{7})+3(\dfrac{\pi}{7})\right)$$ and work with the calculation (in order to reach the $\sqrt7$).

Comment: @Piquito Nobody is able to solve the issue..seems to be a complex issue and not as simple as you said..".a bit of elementary geometry"

Comment: Could you tell us where this problem is taken from?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  It's from another forum...it's not from a specific book or website so there's no additional information..let's hope that colleague piquito can help us and publish his solution since apparently he knows the solution

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Hints: You can use this formula to find area of regular polygon:

$$A=\frac {n\cdot l^2}{4 tan \frac {\pi}n}$$

where n is number of sides, $l$. is length of side. For $l=1$ and $n=7$ we get $A=3.63..$

Now you can find a as :

$\angle KBC=\angle OFH$

because their rays are perpendicular on each other. So we have:

$\triangle KBC\sim \triangle HOF$

$\frac{KB=a}{FH}\frac {BC=1}{OF=r}$

$r=\frac{IF=1/2}{\sin \frac{2\pi}{14}}$

You  finally find $ r\approx 1.2$ and $a=0.78$. For b we have:

$b=FL+a$

You have to show $\angle GFM=\angle HFE\approx 25.7^o$ and in triangle FGM you find:

$FL\approx 0.97\Rightarrow b=0.97+0.87\approx 1.76$

$A=\sqrt 7 a\cdot b\approx 3.63$

That is the formula is correct.

I you want to find formula, then we have:

Sum of angles of heptagon s is:

$s=(2\times 7-4)\frac{\pi}2=5\pi$

$\angle ABC=\frac{5\pi}7$

$\angle KBC=\frac{5\pi}7-\frac{\pi}2=\frac{3\pi}{14} $

$a=1\cdot \cos KBC=\cos\frac{3\pi}{14}\space\space\space\space (1)$

$b_1=FH= FE\cos EFH$

$\angle EFH=\frac {5\pi}7-\frac {\pi}2-\frac{\angle EFH}2$

$\Rightarrow \angle EFH=\frac {\pi}7$

$\Rightarrow b_1=FH=\frac{\pi}7$

$b=a+b_1=\cos \frac{\pi}7+\cos\frac {3\pi}{14}\space\space\space\space (2)$

$A=\frac{7\cdot \cos\frac{\pi}7}{4\cdot \sin \frac {\pi}7}\space\space\space\space (3)$

now you have to find $A=\sqrt 7 ab$ from relation (1) , (2) and (3).

Comment: Exactly..not being able to visualize a solution...it seems like a very complex solution and the colleague said that the solution would be found through the formula with a bit of elementary geometry

Comment: @sirous: Your answer is not the proof of the asked equality (it is just the coincidence of two numbers). If you use, for example, $\sin\left(4(\dfrac{\pi}{7})+3(\dfrac{\pi}{7})\right)=0$ you can be done. Regards.

Comment: If you want not to deduce (you can!), try to use the formula
$$\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)=\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)+\sin\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{7}\right)+\frac{\sqrt7}{2}$$

Comment: @Piquito, thank you for comment. I am not good enough in trigonometry manipulations. I would  like to see your answer using my idea and figure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you don't want to deduce put $x=\dfrac{\pi}{7}$ so you have by given formula $\sqrt7=2\left(\sin(x)-\sin(2x)-\sin(4x)\right)$ so you have just to verify the trigonometric equality
$$2\left(\sin(x)-\sin(2x)-\sin(4x)\right)(\sin^2(X)+\sin(X)\sin(Y)=\frac{7\cos(x)}{4\sin(x)}$$ where $X=\angle{DCG}$ and $Y=\angle{BCG}$ which are easy function of $x$.

With this I end my comments about this problem. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be the diameter of the circumcircle of $ABCDEFG$. Note that $a = BC \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}=d\sin \frac{\pi}{7}\sin \frac{2\pi}{7}$ and $b=AD \sin \frac{2\pi}{7} = d \sin \frac{3\pi}{7} \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}$. On the other hand, the area of $ABCDEFG$ equals $7 \cdot \frac 12 \left(\frac{d}{2}\right) \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}$. The problem boils down to showing that
$$x=\sin \frac{\pi}{7}\sin \frac{2\pi}{7}\sin \frac{3\pi}{7} = \frac{\sqrt 7}{8}.$$

Using $2\sin^2 t = 1-\cos 2t$ we see that
\begin{align*}
8x^2 = 8\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{7}\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin^2 \frac{3\pi}{7} &= \left(1-\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\left(1-\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\right)\left(1-\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}\right) \newline
&= 1 - \left( \cos \frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}\right) + \newline
& \quad +\left( \cos \frac{2\pi}{7}\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}\right) - \newline
& \quad - \cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}.
\end{align*}

Using $\cos t \cos u = \dfrac{\cos(t+u)+\cos(t-u)}{2}$ we get
\begin{align*}\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}+&\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}\cos \frac{2\pi}{7} \newline 
&=\frac{\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}}{2}+\frac{\cos \frac{10\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}}{2}+\frac{\cos \frac{8\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}}{2}\newline 
&=\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}
\end{align*}
since $\cos\frac{8\pi}{7}=\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}$ and $\cos\frac{10\pi}{7}=\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}$.

Moreover, using $\sin 2t = 2 \sin t \cos t$, we have
\begin{align*}
\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{6\pi}{7} &= \cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{8\pi}{7} \newline 
&= \frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{8\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}} \newline 
&= \frac{\frac 12 \sin \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}\cos \frac{8\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}} \newline &= \frac{\frac 14 \sin \frac{8\pi}{7}\cos \frac{8\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}} \newline &= \frac{\frac 18 \sin \frac{16\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}} \newline &= \frac 18.\end{align*}

It follows that $8x^2= 1-\frac 18 = \frac 78$, i.e. $x=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}$, as desired.